# adding JPanel to my frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, frame

I am creating a hang man game.  When the user clicks a button (26 one for each letter), if the letter is guessed correctly, the appropriate blank spots will get letters placed above them.  When I click the first letter that is present in the puzzle word, the image is displayed correctly above the appropriate blank line.  When I click a second letter that belongs in the puzzle word, the letter doesn't get displayed like the first one.  I can not figure out why this is occurring.  Below is my code:

```
public void displayLetterPanel(char letter, int xPlace)
{
    System.out.println("In display letter panel");
    JPanel panelLetter;
    JLabel lblLetter;
    String let = Character.toString(letter); 
    panelLetter = new JPanel();
    panelLetter.setBounds(xPlace, 635, 75, 200);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelLetter);

    lblLetter = new JLabel("");
    lblLetter.setIcon(new ImageIcon(let.toUpperCase() + ".png"));
    panelLetter.add(lblLetter);
    int numLetters = 0;
    for(JPanel num : letters)
    {
        if(num != null)
        {
            numLetters++;
        }
    }

    this.letters[numLetters] = panelLetter;

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i ++)
    {
        if (letters[i] != null)
        {
            System.out.println("In for for showing letters");
            JPanel pan = letters[i];
            pan.enable();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("end of In display letter panel");
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify